# Extract char sequences within a string

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract all text in non-capital letters from this string:

```
a <- "NAME
Agricola, Johannes
ALTERNATIVNAMEN
Schneider, Johann; Schnitter, Johannes; Eisleben, Johannes; Agricola Eisleben, Johannes; Bauer, Hans
KURZBESCHREIBUNG
deutscher Reformator
GEBURTSDATUM
20. April 1494
GEBURTSORT
Eisleben
STERBEDATUM
22. September 1566
STERBEORT
Berlin"
```

In order to extract "Agricola, Johannes", I tried something like:

```
# Name
name <- sub("\\s*ALTERNATIVNAMEN\\b.*", "", a)
cat(sub("NAME", "", name))
```

but I don't know how to continue. My problem is that I don't get how to express the following using a Regex: "Match everything after NAME until ALTERNATIVNAMEN". In the end, I would like to have 7 variables holding the personal data as character objects. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read.table(text=gsub("([[:upper:]])\\n","\\1:",a),sep=":")
                V1                                                                                                   V2
1             NAME                                                                                   Agricola, Johannes
2  ALTERNATIVNAMEN Schneider, Johann; Schnitter, Johannes; Eisleben, Johannes; Agricola Eisleben, Johannes; Bauer, Hans
3 KURZBESCHREIBUNG                                                                                 deutscher Reformator
4     GEBURTSDATUM                                                                                       20. April 1494
5       GEBURTSORT                                                                                             Eisleben
6      STERBEDATUM                                                                                   22. September 1566
7        STERBEORT                                                                                               Berlin
```

You can then pick the column you want

Comment: Great, this seems to be another option! But why is the separator of the read.table function a colon?

Comment: The gsub function replaces the line break at the end of each uppercase word with a colon. And that becomes your separator..

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strsplit` and split at any sequence of two or more capital letters...

```
strsplit(a,"[A-Z]{2,}")

[[1]]
[1] ""                                                                                                        
[2] "\nAgricola, Johannes\n"                                                                                  
[3] "\nSchneider, Johann; Schnitter, Johannes; Eisleben, Johannes; Agricola Eisleben, Johannes; Bauer, Hans\n"
[4] "\ndeutscher Reformator\n"                                                                                
[5] "\n20. April 1494\n"                                                                                      
[6] "\nEisleben\n"                                                                                            
[7] "\n22. September 1566\n"                                                                                  
[8] "\nBerlin"
```

Comment: That's great! But how do i store each substring into a variable? And how can I get rid of the "\n" in this case?

Comment: `gsub("\n", "", a)` takes care of the latter

Comment: Something like `as.data.frame(gsub("\\n","",do.call(rbind,strsplit(a,"[A-Z]{2,}"))))` will turn a vector of `a`s into a dataframe of the variables you want.

Comment: try `read.table(text=gsub("([[:upper:]])\\n","\\1:",a),sep=":")`